# VIM with Tree on OS X

Tags: macos, vim, tree, text-editor

I want to do text editing on a Mac and what I'd like to have is:

> - VIM editor built in
> - a tree view to open and switch between files more quickly

Should I go with vim and a tree plugin? Or is there a good text editing program with VIM built-in?

What are your experiences with that combination? Do you have any other recommendation?

Comment: I use [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) with [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658), but lots of people swear by [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (commercial).

Comment: Using a tree view with vim is a contradiction of the vim concept. The idea of vim is to use the keyboard and not the mouse. Instead I would be looking at the command-t plugin or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that plugin, I'll have a look at it. But I have to say, when you have a full hierarchy of folders and files then it's just harder to remember a path or filename than to see a visual representation of the hierarchy in front of you. Vim provides many features that I don't want to miss and still for my purpose it's good to have mouse interaction on the tree. I believe it doesn't hurt the vim concept. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) with [macvim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/).

Comment: it took me two hours to install everything and configure it right, but i guess i'm ready to go, this was exactly what i needed! ;-)

Comment: @ka2011r Wow. Really glad you liked it!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried gvim for mac http://macvim.org/OSX/index.php

I don't have a mac but do use gvim on various windows and linux installs.

Answer (score 0):

**Use VIM explorer**

Vim has file explorer with standard installation, to open it on the left side, first open file with vim and do:

```
:vs
```

This will split the window in half with the same file, then:

```
:E
```

or

```
:Explore
```

there is help at the top and standard vim navigation works to open file or directory just hit Enter. To enable tree like view in there you will need this to be added to your ~/.vimrc:

```
g:netrw_liststyle=3
```

I never tried the above solutions but benefit of this is that you can get it working in couple of minutes with out of the box vim.

**Bonus Feature**

If you open directory with vim just hit i to change the modes.